# How can I plot a histogram with read_excel and barplot?

Tags: r

I have a Excel worksheet named crime.xlsx that has X-Age and Y-Frequency. I want it to show how many times a crime has happened for each age group.

[image]

In RStudio I have created a new R Markdown and I now want to use read_excel and barplot to plot the data.

```
library("readxl")
res <- read_excel("crime.xlsx", sheet = 1)
head(res[, 1:2])
barplot(res)
```

This gives me the following error:

> Error in barplot.default(res) : 'height' must be a vector or a matric
> Calls: Anonymous withVisible -> eval -> eval -> barplot ->
> barplot.default in addition: Warning message: package readxl was built
> under R version 4.0.5

Im running
Windows 10 with
RStudio 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula interface of `barplot` :

```
res <- readxl::read_excel("crime.xlsx", sheet = 1)
barplot(Y~X, res)
```

Comment: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : Object Y not found Calls: Anonymous ... eval -> Anonymous - model.fram.default -> eval -> eval

Comment: @Europa Replace `X` and `Y` with the exact column names that you have in `res`. If you still receive an error please add `dput(head(res[, 1:2]))` to your post.

Comment: But how can I do this @Ronak Shah ? I've only used R for 6 months.

Comment: This worked: barplot(``Y - Frequency``~``X - Age``, res)